# Customize the Spinner Dialog with transparent background color and has divider between its items

Tags: android, spinner

I have successfully designed a dialog spinner as shown below. Now what I want is to set the background color of the spinner to be transparent and add the divider between the items.

What I have done is adding a "Spinner Style" style of the spinner in `styles.xml` with `android:divider`, `android:height` divider and `android:padding` attributes, and then add the style attribute to the Spinner, however, the result is no different.

On the other hand, I have tried to merely change the color of the spinner pop up a background to be transparent, however, this result is not my desired one.

Hence, I hope to see any advice and documents to solve this problem! Thanks for all help!

[my current spinner pop up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7y2xK.png) and what I want could look like [desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btyoo.png)(the autocomplete view is irrelevant; I just care about the background and divider between the items)

```
 **customize_spinner_shape_in_search_frame.xml**


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    style="@style/spinnerStyle">

    <!-- view background color -->
    <solid
        android:color="#EFB1B9" >
    </solid>

    <corners
        android:radius="20dp"   >
    </corners>

</shape>


 **Spinner in layout.xml**

     <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/search_criteria_activity_spn_subject_title"
        android:layout_width="188dp"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog"
        android:backgroundTintMode="add"
        android:background="@drawable/customize_spinner_shape_in_search_frame"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/search_criteria_activity_s2"
        style="@style/spinnerStyle"/>

 **And lastly, the SpinnerStyle in styles.xml:**

     <style name="spinnerStyle"  parent="Widget.AppCompat.Spinner">
        <item name="android:divider">#d1d1d1</item>
        <item name="android:dividerHeight">0.5dp</item>
        <item name="android:padding">5sp</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Hi Please post your code. I will let you know what changes we have to do there.

Comment: Dear Pankaj, I have added some code Snippet related to such spinner

Answer (score 0):

You can use **android:popupBackground="@android:color/transparent"** to change Popup background to transparent

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/search_criteria_activity_spn_subject_title"
        android:layout_width="188dp"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog"
        android:backgroundTintMode="add"
        android:background="@drawable/customize_spinner_shape_in_search_frame"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/search_criteria_activity_s2"
        style="@style/spinnerStyle"
        android:popupBackground="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

Comment: Dear Pankaj, I have add this attribute, however, nothing still changed, I think there need something else? Actually, I have tried this before.

Comment: Just remove android:background and check it once.

Comment: The result stayed the same!

Comment: Let's wait for other guys to answer the solution. I will check it on my Android studio and let you know soon